# pyspark dataframe split column error. How to solve it?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

```
df4[['Title','FirstName','LastName']]=df3.USER_FULL_NAME.str.split(r'\D', expand=True)
```

I got the below error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [121], line 2
      1 #df[['V','allele']] = df['V'].str.split('-',expand=True)
----> 2 df4[['Title','FirstName','LastName']]=df3.USER_FULL_NAME.str.split(r'\D', expand=True)

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `df3` is something like this:

```bash
+---+--------------+
| ID|USER_FULL_NAME|
+---+--------------+
|  1|     Mr. AA BB|
|  2|    Mrs. BB CC|
|  3|     Dr. DD EE|
|  4|    PhD. FF GG|
+---+--------------+
```

You can split the `USER_FULL_NAME` and create a new `DataFrame` with the following code:

```py
df4 = df3.select(
        'Id',
        *[
            F.split(df3.USER_FULL_NAME, ' ').getItem(i).alias(col_name)
            for i, col_name in enumerate(('Title', 'FirstName', 'LastName'))
        ]
    )
```

In this case, `df4` will be:

```bash
+---+-----+---------+--------+
| Id|Title|FirstName|LastName|
+---+-----+---------+--------+
|  1|  Mr.|       AA|      BB|
|  2| Mrs.|       BB|      CC|
|  3|  Dr.|       DD|      EE|
|  4| PhD.|       FF|      GG|
+---+-----+---------+--------+
```

Instead, if you want to add the three columns to an already existing `DataFrame` with the `Id` of the user, you can join the `df4` with the other `DataFrame`. Suppose that the input DataFrame is `df2`:

```bash
+---+--------+
| ID|Greeting|
+---+--------+
|  1|   Hello|
|  2|   Hallo|
|  4|    Ciao|
+---+--------+
```

Then, the following code will join the two `DataFrame`s:

```py
df2.join(df4, 'Id', 'left')
```

resulting in:

```bash
+---+--------+-----+---------+--------+
| ID|Greeting|Title|FirstName|LastName|
+---+--------+-----+---------+--------+
|  1|   Hello|  Mr.|       AA|      BB|
|  2|   Hallo| Mrs.|       BB|      CC|
|  4|    Ciao| PhD.|       FF|      GG|
+---+--------+-----+---------+--------+
```

The third option could be to add the three columns to `df3`:

```py
split_column = F.split(F.col('USER_FULL_NAME'), ' ')
for i, col_name in enumerate(('Title', 'FirstName', 'LastName')):
    df3 = df3.withColumn(col_name, split_column.getItem(i))
```

In this case, the result will be:

```bash
+---+--------------+-----+---------+--------+
| ID|USER_FULL_NAME|Title|FirstName|LastName|
+---+--------------+-----+---------+--------+
|  1|     Mr. AA BB|  Mr.|       AA|      BB|
|  2|    Mrs. BB CC| Mrs.|       BB|      CC|
|  3|     Dr. DD EE|  Dr.|       DD|      EE|
|  4|    PhD. FF GG| PhD.|       FF|      GG|
+---+--------------+-----+---------+--------+
```